# STM32F4 FSMC/FMC SRAM as Heap/Stack results in random hardfaults

Tags: arm, heap-memory, stm32, ram, cortex-m

we are currently evaluating to use an external SRAM for C/C++ heap storage on our platform using a STM32F439BI microcontroller.

**The problem**

Using the SRAM as storage for heap results in random hardfaults which are raised from buserrors/imprecice buserrors.
Without placing the heap on the SRAM, memory tests run successfully on the whole SRAM (8 bit/16 bit and 32 bit accesses).
Connecting a debugger I can observe these errors sometimes before a hardfault occurs. Most often a word is read from the SRAM and the CPU register fills with addresses of the following format: 0x-1F3-1F3 (- is most often '0', sometimes 'A' or '6'). The pattern '1F3' persists. If the same address is read again some lines further down the correct value is read (some other address in 0x60000000 space).
If I stop the program on a breakpoint at some point early in the program and step a few lines, I get these errors more frequently.

**Further details**

- The SRAM is connected using the FMC/FSMC peripheral on FMC bank 1 and SRAM bank 1 and is therefore memory-mapped to address 0x60000000.
- All settings for GPIO pins and FMC configuration are set from the startup file before main() executes or static objects are created.
- The SRAM is the following: [CY7C1041GN30](http://www.cypress.com/file/221596/download)
- We connect all 16 data pins, all 18 address pins, BHE, BLE, OE, WE and CE to our controller. All pins are configured as push-pull-alternate-function, pull-up, AF_12 (FMC), very high speed. We enable clocks for all necessary pins and the clock for FMC. Note: Initially we started out without pull-up/down showing the same symptoms.
- The controller runs with a clock speed of 168 MHz
- As stated above, a memory test runs successfully
- We use DMA for SPI, I2C and ADC data transfers
- We frequently use interrupts, including external (pin) interrupts
- We use the following timing settings:

  - AddressSetupTime:      2
  - AddressHoldTime:       4
  - DataSetupTime:         4
  - BusTurnAroundDuration: 1
  - CLKDivision:           2
  - DataLatency:           2
- We configure the FMC as follows:

  - NSBank              FMC_NORSRAM_BANK1,
  - DataAddressMux      FMC_DATA_ADDRESS_MUX_DISABLE,
  - MemoryType          FMC_MEMORY_TYPE_SRAM,
  - MemoryDataWidth     FMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16,
  - BurstAccessMode     FMC_BURST_ACCESS_MODE_DISABLE,
  - WaitSignalPolarity  FMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_POLARITY_LOW,
  - WrapMode            FMC_WRAP_MODE_DISABLE,
  - WaitSignalActive    FMC_WAIT_TIMING_BEFORE_WS,
  - WriteOperation      FMC_WRITE_OPERATION_ENABLE,
  - WaitSignal          FMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_DISABLE,
  - ExtendedMode        FMC_EXTENDED_MODE_DISABLE,
  - AsynchronousWait    FMC_ASYNCHRONOUS_WAIT_DISABLE,
  - WriteBurst          FMC_WRITE_BURST_DISABLE,
  - ContinuousClock     FMC_CONTINUOUS_CLOCK_SYNC_ASYNC,
  - WriteFifo           0,
  - PageSize            0
- We spend a lot of time of experimenting with longer timings and compared all the settings to examples including this one: [Using STM32L476/486 FSMC peripheral
  to drive external memories](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/3f/38/6c/cc/0b/7b/41/b7/DM00228015.pdf/files/DM00228015.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00228015.pdf) (although this one is for the STM32L4, I am fairly certain it applies to this controller as well)

**Findings on similar problems**

- The problem sounds very similar to this [errata sheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/38/e6/37/64/08/38/45/67/DM00068628.pdf/files/DM00068628.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00068628.pdf) entry: "2.3.4 Corruption of data read from the FMC" **but it also says the error is fixed in our revision of the controller (3)**

I hope someone out there has seen this strange behaviour before and can help us. After over one week of debugging we expect some kind of error in the controller when interrupts/DMA accesses occur while the CPU accesses the SRAM (when we use it as heap, it is accessed very frequently). Hopefully you can shed some light on this topic.

Comment: *All pins are configured as pull-up* I think they should rather be configured as push-pull, no pull-up. That's how the STM32F429-Discovery sample projects do it.

Comment: Hi @berendi thank you for your reply. You are probably right about that. Initially we configured the pin as alternate function push-pull w/o pullup/down. But we had the same symptoms. I updated the post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not getting back to you, internet.

Yes, we found out what the issue was (at least in our case). Problem was that the J-Link debugger we use is causing problems if it hangs above the power electronics on our pcb (it is mounted vertically). If we guide the ribbon cable out at the top (only digital electronics) the error disappears. So our guess is, that some noise from the electronics was caught up by the cable and directly injected into the JTAG port, which caused failures inside the MCU.

Answer (score -1):

Just got a confirmation from ST, that there is a bug in the STM32F469 FMC that might cause incorrect values if the write fifo is disabled. The workaround is to have the fifo enabled. It is the same issue as in this F7 processor https://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/dm00145382.pdf

Comment: All those addresses are actually invalid.

Comment: It looks like you have erratic flash reads resulting in the wrong access addresses

Comment: Yes the addresses are invalid. That is the problem, that the FMC does not return valid data.
The problem might be erratic flash reads, but we are reading from internal flash and the problem still occurs when more waitstates are added (5WS ->8WS). And we never see UsageFault's due to invalid instructions.

Comment: 0x4b43 4b43 what is this?

Comment: 0x4b43 4b43 is a random address not pointing anywhere. 0x4008 0000 - 0x4fff ffff is marked as reserved in the datasheet. It is after valid AHB1 area and before AHB2 area

Comment: So what is the logic of showing us random addresses. Where did you take it from?

Comment: That is the value provided by the FMC when the error occurs.
The intention was to illustrate that we get different wrong values depending on flash timing, but they all have the same pattern as the original question.

Comment: See my new answer above, maybe it helps.